# Using row index number to calculate values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm having trouble using the row number as index. For example I want a new column that will give me the sales taking into account the next 4 days. I want to create column name:sale_next 4

The issue with my code is that I don't know how to make the index of the `row_number()` variable, since what I'm doing is fetching the actual value of the column.

```
#heres to create the data
df <- read.table(text = "day    price   price_change    sales   High_sales_ind
1 5 0   12  1
2   5   0   6   0
3   5   0   5   0
4   5   0   4   0
5   5   0   10  1
6   5   0   10  1
7   5   0   10  1
8   5   0   12  1
9   5   0   14  1
10  7   2   3   0
11  7   0   2   0", header = TRUE)


#my code

df<- df %>% mutate(sales_next4 = sales[row_number():sales_rownumber()+4)
```

What I need:

| day | price | price_change | sales | High_sales_ind | sales_next4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 0 | 12 | 1 | 27 |
| 2 | 5 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 25 |
| 3 | 5 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 29 |
| 4 | 5 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 34 |
| 5 | 5 | 0 | 10 | 1 | 42 |
| 6 | 5 | 0 | 10 | 1 | 46 |
| 7 | 5 | 0 | 10 | 1 | 39 |
| 8 | 5 | 0 | 12 | 1 | 31 |
| 9 | 5 | 0 | 14 | 1 | 19 |
| 10 | 7 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 5 |
| 11 | 7 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 2 |

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rollapply` from the `zoo` package for cases like this, assuming that the days are consecutive as in the example data provided.

You'll need to use the `partial =`  and `align =`  arguments to fill the column correctly, see `?rollapply` for the details.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(sales_next4 = rollapply(sales, 4, sum, partial = TRUE, align = "left"))
```

Result:

```
   day price price_change sales High_sales_ind sales_next4
1    1     5            0    12              1          27
2    2     5            0     6              0          25
3    3     5            0     5              0          29
4    4     5            0     4              0          34
5    5     5            0    10              1          42
6    6     5            0    10              1          46
7    7     5            0    10              1          39
8    8     5            0    12              1          31
9    9     5            0    14              1          19
10  10     7            2     3              0           5
11  11     7            0     2              0           2
```

Comment: Nice solution! But this method works only when the `day` column is consecutive.

Comment: I'm assuming that it is, based on the example data. If it is not then @jontieez can provide a more realistic example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` from `purrr` to do rolling sum depending on the `day` column.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(sales_next4 = map_dbl(day, ~ sum(sales[between(day, .x, .x+3)])))

#    day price price_change sales High_sales_ind sales_next4
# 1    1     5            0    12              1          27
# 2    2     5            0     6              0          25
# 3    3     5            0     5              0          29
# 4    4     5            0     4              0          34
# 5    5     5            0    10              1          42
# 6    6     5            0    10              1          46
# 7    7     5            0    10              1          39
# 8    8     5            0    12              1          31
# 9    9     5            0    14              1          19
# 10  10     7            2     3              0           5
# 11  11     7            0     2              0           2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `slider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(slider)
df %>% 
  mutate(sales_next4 = slide_dbl(day, ~ sum(sales[.x]), .after = 3))
   day price price_change sales High_sales_ind sales_next4
1    1     5            0    12              1          27
2    2     5            0     6              0          25
3    3     5            0     5              0          29
4    4     5            0     4              0          34
5    5     5            0    10              1          42
6    6     5            0    10              1          46
7    7     5            0    10              1          39
8    8     5            0    12              1          31
9    9     5            0    14              1          19
10  10     7            2     3              0           5
11  11     7            0     2              0           2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Reduce()` and `data.table::shift()`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, n4:=Reduce(`+`,shift(c(sales,0,0,0),-3:0))[1:.N]]
```

Output:

```
   day price price_change sales High_sales_ind sales_next4
1    1     5            0    12              1          27
2    2     5            0     6              0          25
3    3     5            0     5              0          29
4    4     5            0     4              0          34
5    5     5            0    10              1          42
6    6     5            0    10              1          46
7    7     5            0    10              1          39
8    8     5            0    12              1          31
9    9     5            0    14              1          19
10  10     7            2     3              0           5
11  11     7            0     2              0           2
```

or, could this as part of dplyr/mutate pipeline

```
mutate(df, sales_next4 = Reduce(`+`, data.table::shift(c(sales,0,0,0),0:-3))[1:nrow(df)])
```